# Tinymce text color

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, tinymce

I have a simple html page in which some text is shown from a database in tinymce. The user has the option to edit it. What I want is that when the user clicks the edit button, the text color changes to blue, so that whatever they type in appears blue. I want to keep the default tinymce colour *before* the user has typed something in themself and only have the new colour on the text they enter.

How can I do that?

Comment: Probably this link helps you here : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:content_css

Comment: but they are perform during initialization, i want to change it after some action

Comment: Have you tried to change the class of the parent element of the editor with javascript when clicking on the edit button (and defining the class inside the editors css-file with blue text color?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: i ended up making a string outside like this

$str = "<p><font color = \"red\">" . $mysecond_str . "</font></p>;

then i fed it to the tinymce text editor via javascript:

var textarea_value = <?php echo json_encode($display_min); ?>;  document.getElementById('mytextarea').value = textarea_value;


this got the job done, atleast for now!

Answer (score 0):

i ended up making a string outside like this:

```
$str = "<p><font color = \"red\">" . $mysecond_str . "</font></p>;
```

then i fed it to the tinymce text editor via javascript:

```
var textarea_value = <?php echo json_encode($str); ?>; 
document.getElementById('mytextarea').value = textarea_value;
```

this got the job done, atleast for now!